# how to resolve "java.lang.RuntimeException" error

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, google-maps-api-2, android-maps-v2

I'm new to android. I built an application in which there is a `Button` which starts an `Activity` and there are two more `Buttons` in that `Activity` which will open two seperate activities. One of that `Activity` contains Google map named as nearby search. When I start the nearby search the app is crashing while this `Activity` was running perfectly before integrating the map.

**Here is the log cat**

```
04-02 02:32:40.354: E/AndroidRuntime(22037): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jamaat_times/com.example.jamaattiming.NearbySearch}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-02 02:32:40.354: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
04-02 02:32:40.354: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
04-02 02:32:40.354: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
04-02 02:32:40.354: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
04-02 02:32:40.354: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
04-02 02:32:40.354: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
04-02 02:32:40.354: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
04-02 02:32:40.354: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 02:32:40.354: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-02 02:32:40.354: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
04-02 02:32:40.354: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
04-02 02:32:40.354: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-02 02:32:40.354: E/AndroidRuntime(22037): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-02 02:32:40.354: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):    at com.example.jamaattiming.NearbySearch.onCreate(NearbySearch.java:36)
04-02 02:32:40.354: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
04-02 02:32:40.354: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
04-02 02:32:40.354: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
04-02 02:32:40.354: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):    ... 11 more
```

**here is the java file:**

```
    public class NearbySearch extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nearby_search);
        GoogleMapOptions mapOptions = new GoogleMapOptions();
         GoogleMap maps=(((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map2)).getMap());

         mapOptions.mapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
         //maps.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
         maps.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
         maps.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(24.9967 , 66.1234))
            .title("Hello world"));
    }

}
```

**here is the xml file:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#808080">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map2"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.jamaat_times"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

  <uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="8"
      android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_jamaat"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.jamaattiming.Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.jamaattiming.MainPage"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.CLEARSCREEN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.jamaattiming.Qibla"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.COMPASS" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.jamaattiming.JamaatFinder"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_jamaat_finder" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.jamaattiming.QiblaFinder"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_qibla_finder" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.jamaattiming.TagYourself"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tag_yourself" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="my key" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.jamaattiming.NearbySearch"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_nearby_search" >
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name="com.example.jamaattiming.ManualSearch"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_manual_search" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Google Null Pointer Exceptions and learn how to fix them yourself. It'll be a valuable experience in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this

```
<uses-sdk
  android:minSdkVersion="8"
```

to

```
<uses-sdk
  android:minSdkVersion="12"
```

as you should using `MapFragment` from api level above 11

It looks like `GooleMap` object `maps` is null. It is better to check the Availability of google play services before initializing map object.

Look at **Check for Google Play Services**

http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Follow

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

> public final GoogleMap getMap ()
>
> Gets the underlying GoogleMap that is tied to the view wrapped by this
>   fragment.
>
> Returns the GoogleMap. Null if the view of the fragment is not yet
>   ready. This can happen if the fragment lifecyle have not gone through
>   onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) yet. This can also
>   happen if Google Play services is not available. If Google Play
>   services becomes available afterwards and the fragment have gone
>   through onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle), calling this
>   method again will initialize and return the GoogleMap.

Comment: thanks a lot sir my problem has resolved. I have declare a MapView object mv which was returning null value. That was the line 36. 
There is a question in my mind that how can you predict the line which is creating trouble by looking at the log cat?

Comment: @user3144474 not predicting but looking at stacktrace the caused by part` Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-02 02:32:40.354: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):    at com.example.jamaattiming.NearbySearch.onCreate(NearbySearch.java:36)`. What does that say `NearbySearch.java:36`

Comment: @user3144474 there could be one more problem package name is manifest  is `com.example.jamaat_times` and for activity its `com.example.jamaattiming.Splash`. make sure you have them declared properly

Comment: @user3144474 still its better you check availability of google play services. I don't think you have done that. And where does MapView come from?. I don't see a mapview anywhere